# How to understand exchange pattern?

Tags: representation-theory, cluster-algebra

I am reading an paper "cluster algebras I: foundations" by Fomin and Zelevinsky.

Let $I = \{1,2, \ldots, n\}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ a cluster.

For each $t \in \mathbb{T}_n$, let $\mathbf{x}(t) = (x_i(t))_{i \in I}$. All variables will commute and satisfy the following exchange relations, for $t \overset{j}{-} t'$ in $\mathbb{T}_n$:
\begin{align}
& x_i(t) = x_i (t') \textrm{ for any $i \neq j$}; \\
& x_j (t)x_j (t') = M_j(t)(\mathbf{x}(t)) + M_j(t')(\mathbf{x}(t')).
\end{align}

$\mathbf{Definition 2.1}$ An exchange pattern on $\mathbb{T}_n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{P}$ is a family of monomials $\mathcal{M} = (M_j(t))_{t \in \mathbb{T}_n, j \in I}$ of the form 
\begin{align*}
M_j(t) = p_j(t) \prod_{i \in I} x_i^{b_i}, \ p_j(t) \in \mathbb{P}, \ b_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0},
\end{align*}
satistfying the following four axioms:

E1. If $t \in \mathbb{T}_n$, then $x_j \not \mid M_j (t)$.

E2. If $t_1 \overset{j}{-} t_2$ and $x_i \mid M_j (t_1)$, then $x_i \not \mid M_j (t_2)$.

E3.  If $t_1 \overset{i}{-} t_2 \overset{j}{-} t_3$, then $x_j \mid M_i (t_1)$ if and only if $x_i \mid M_j (t_2)$.

E4. Let If $t_1 \overset{i}{-} t_2 \overset{j}{-} t_3 \overset{i}{-} t_4$. Then $\frac{M_i(t_3)}{M_i(t_4)} = \frac{M_i(t_2)}{M_i(t_1)}|_{x_j \leftarrow \frac{M_{0}}{x_j}}$, where $M_0 = (M_j(t_2) + M_j(t_3))|_{x_i = 0}$.

E2 $\Rightarrow$ $M_j (t_1)$ and $M_j (t_2)$ are two monomials without common divisors in $ \mathbf{x} - {x_j}$.  I do not know what E3 and E4 mean.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Could you tell us which aspect of E3 and E4 you have trouble with?

Comment: @ Pierre-Guy Plamondon I want to know why the authors define E3 and E4. What background? Or other reason.